# Difference between WebLogic and WebSphere?

Tags: websphere, weblogic

I am not able to find actual differences between these two Java EE servers.

From my past experience, I found out following:

1. WL is evolving more faster than WAS.
2. WL is more user friendly than WAS. To simply deploy a application in WAS, we need to go in deep and its difficult to find if u are new to it.
3. I found out that WAS is slower in some machine than WL.
4. I found out that Classloading is easier to understand and effective in WL than WAS

***Above all are my experiences but not actual facts. Am I correct in all my findings?***
I want to know more in this respect. Please clear my doubts. If possible please provide each Java EE server's pros and cons.

**I need to find more differences in respect to pros and cons, performance, security, usability and classloading.**

Comment: You already wrote the pros and cons (WLS >> WAS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, Weblogic is *currently and in my mind* superior to Websphere, but there is no proof of it.

Java EE technology is moving and the answer really depends on your application architecture, and the pros/cons features you're (potentially) using on each server, and the global environment (Is it for use in a complete IBM information system with bunch of IBM products such MQ, WAS Portal etc...)

Based on my experience, regarding developper usability and deployer usability, I prefer Weblogic since I get:

- less troubles with JAXWS web services on WL (and by the way Jboss) than in WAS
- troubles with EJB 2.1 on Websphere : EJB stubs not required on WL (and Jboss btw), several instance of WAS on the same host having EJBs not working with default configuration, etc...
- a better user experience with WL console (but a better experience with WAS admin scripts)
- a lot of fix pack to install on Websphere (but at least they exist :-) )

Regarding classloading, you should refer to Java doc stuff, even if you can tweak some things that I would not recommend (but it shouldn't be the case since you're evoking J2EE).

Regarding performances I think it is subjective and depends on the JVM, the OS, the hardware.

Regarding security I have no opinion, it is complex anyway.

Answer (score 4):

One is made by IBM, the other is made by BEA (now Oracle). What's the actual question here?

Comment: I want to know about difference between WL and WAS server in terms of performance,security and usability. Pros and cons of each server.

Answer (score 1):

Abhishek,

Ask the vendors for their comparison charts and then you should be able to see the answers. People (vendors too) are prejudiced as always. The vendors would highlight the strengths of their respective products so by looking at both their docs from their sales folks you should be able to make your assessments on these products.

As I work primarily in WebSphere, I can provide you some info.  I am refraining from making any comparisons here.

WebSphere Application Server comes in a number of flavors: (the keys ones are listed below)

- WebSphere ND (which is typically used)
- WebSphere CE (which is built on top of Geronimo Server)
- WebSphere XD (for very large deployments)

Ensure that you compare the equivalent products in Web Logic or the other vendors.

HTH
Manglu

Answer (score 0):

WAS is not user friendly where as WL is.  WAS is slower than WL for sure.  i worked for both product companies and WL is way way better than WAS in many ways.