# best server in java in terms of load handing

Tags: jakarta-ee

Can any body say which one is the best server in terms of handling the load. Can any body give the matrix which comprises different servers and their capacities.

Comment: I personally think WebSphere sucks big time and if you're not using an IBM stack, just stay away from it. Here are some other opinions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224822/websphere-vs-weblogic and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604595/difference-between-weblogic-and-websphere. But you should actually run your own benchmarks with your own app. First, you can't trust vendor's benchmarks and 2. you can almost make them say whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "No".

A slightly longer answer:

There are Java EE benchmarks out there, for example [here](http://www.spec.org/jEnterprise2010/). I think it is very difficult to extrapolate from these to your real-world needs.

In my experience the application's design and implementation has a far more impact on the performance achieved than the particular Java EE server you pick. Also each vendor may have a "sweet spot" or some particular feature that happens to fit your requirements. So what's "best" today ma not be "best" tomorrow when your needs change or the vendors improve their products.

Also note that making things go quickly is one challenge, but the other non-functional aspects such as reliability, fault tolerance and ease of administration are also important.

(disclaimer, I'm an IBM WebSphere consultant so I can't claim to be unbiased. So if you wanted a partisan someone to say which is "best" I'd be happy to tell you ;-)